# how to format json dumps

Tags: python, json, string-formatting

I got json dumps like this:

```
"aaa": {
    "bbb": {
        "ccc": {
            "ddd": "string1",
            "eee": "string2"
        }
    },
    "kkk": "string3"
}
```

And I'd like to format it this way: enclose every key-value pair (separated by `:`) with `{}` and then replace `:` with `,`.

I know that I can use `re.sub()` to replace string patterns, but regular expression does not work with overlapping patterns, so I can match, for example, `"ddd": "string1"` but not `"ccc": {...}` ***at the same time***.

For the above json string, I'd like to get:

```
{"aaa", {
    {"bbb", {
        {"ccc", {
            {"ddd", "string1"},
            {"eee", "string2"}
        }}
    }},
    {"kkk", "string3"}
}}
```

Comment: Do you understand that the resulting output is not valid JSON? Do you have another tool that can parse this?

Comment: @AlexHall yes, I do understand it's not a valid json format. The resulting output will be used by C++ code.

Comment: Actually the input is not valid JSON either, e.g. `"ddd": no_quote_string1,`. Strings are always quoted in JSON. What produced this? If it was valid JSON that might make it easier to solve the problem.

Comment: OK. I'll edit the question to make it easier. The original string was a valid json, I stripped double quotes from no_quote_string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hack which converts everything to lists and then changes square brackets to curly ones. If your strings might contain square brackets that'll be a problem.

```py
import json

inp = """
{
    "aaa": {
        "bbb": {
            "ccc": {
                "ddd": "string1",
                "eee": "string2"
            }
        },
        "kkk": "string3"
    }
}
"""

inp = json.loads(inp)


def items(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return [(k, items(v)) for k, v in d.items()]
    return d


inp = items(inp)

print(json.dumps(inp, indent=2).replace("[", "{").replace("]", "}"))
```

Output:

```
{
  {
    "aaa",
    {
      {
        "bbb",
        {
          {
            "ccc",
            {
              {
                "ddd",
                "string1"
              },
              {
                "eee",
                "string2"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "kkk",
        "string3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfect! Could you give me some hints on how to use it with an object's __dict__ attribute? This is how I prepare for the inp string in my code: json.loads(json.dumps(myobject, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)). It seems like I have done a lot of redundent work here. Do you know how to directly work on myobject? I basically dump all its attributes to json and then load it back to a json object....

Comment: Try that with `default=lambda o: o.__dict__.items()` and see what happens. If there are any actual dicts in your objects the recursive `items` function will still be needed.

Comment: Note this hack only works with Python 3.7+ because of http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/02/27/python-3-7-dictionaries-now-ordered/

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are treating dictionary keys as ordered when they aren't, so I made it more explicit with lists.

If it were me, I wouldn't dump to JSON in the first place, I'd serialize the native python data structure straight to C++ initializer list syntax:

```
myobj = {
  "aaa": [
    { "bbb": {
        "ccc": [
            {"ddd": "string1"},
            {"eee": "string2"}
        ]
    }},
    { "kkk": "string3" }
  ]
}

def pyToCpp(value, key=None):
  if key:
    return '{{ "{}", {} }}'.format(key, pyToCpp(value))
  if type(value) == dict:
    for k, v in value.items():
      return pyToCpp(v, k)
  elif type(value) == list:
    l = [pyToCpp(v) for v in value]
    return '{{ {} }}'.format(", ".join(l))
  else:
    return '"{}"'.format(value)

y = pyToCpp(myobj)
print(y)
```

Output:

```
{ "aaa", { { "bbb", { "ccc", { { "ddd", "string1" }, { "eee", "string2" } } } }, { "kkk", "string3" } } }
```

Run it here: https://repl.it/repls/OddFrontUsers

Comment: Does it work with different number of nested {} pairs? The json file that I have here may have various levels of nested {}.

Comment: Yes, it is recursive, it should work with arbitrarily deep nesting. If you give an example I can verify.